# Alignment of list of endnotes

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes, endnotes

I have a number of footnotes and endnotes that are included at the end of a document. The first endnote is not aligned with the rest of the end/footnotes:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{endnotes} 
\let\footnote\endnote
\renewcommand\enoteheading{\chapter{Notes}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{chapter}

\section{section}
first\footnote{hello}, 

second\endnote{this is my equation
\begin{equation}
z=x+y
\end{equation}
}

third\endnote{another equation $a+b+c$}

\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notes}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

It currently looks like:
[image]

but I want all notes to be aligned with the first one. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below **macro** in preamble part:

```
\renewcommand\enoteformat{\rightskip=0pt \leftskip=0pt \parindent=0em
  \leavevmode\makeenmark\raggedright}
```

[image]

Comment: you really shouldn't need `\rightskip=0pt` since \raggedright` resets it.